# npm install doesn't load the correct packages

Tags: angular

my supervisor sent me a `git repository`
after i cloned it and running `npm install`
i still git missing `packages` or packages which don't work with each others[have conflicts].
is there any tool to solve this conflicts in dependencies versions?
this is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "ang2-conduit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.85",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.6.1",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.11.14",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/marked": "^0.0.28",
    "@types/node": "~7.0.16",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.2"
  }
}
```

running `npm install` returns:

```
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha1-LePXGIGbwgFldUxKWa+36YM/Zwc= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-LePXGIGbwgFldUxKWa+36YM/Zwc= but got sha512-UBYHWph6P3tutkbXpW6XYg9ZPbTKjw/YC2hGG1/GEvWwTbvezBUv3h+mmUFw79T3RFPnmedpiXdOBbXX+4l0jg==. (51120 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.

> node-sass@4.9.3 install /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /home/linux/.npm/node-sass/4.9.3/linux-x64-57_binding.node

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @angular/animations@4.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-chips@1.9.4 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-chips@1.9.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-chips@1.9.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-chips@1.9.4 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-chips@1.9.4 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package @angular/compiler-cli is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1177 packages in 50.639s
```

after that i run `ng build` and i get:

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css ./libs/css/theme.css ./libs/css/bootstrap.css ./libs/css/bootstrap-theme.css ./libs/css/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css ./libs/css/owl.carousel.css ./libs/css/rangeslider.css ./libs/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css ./libs/css/animate.css ./libs/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css ./node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite'
ERROR in ./src/app/add-auctionbatch/add-auctionbatch.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/add-auctionbatch'
ERROR in ./src/app/display-user/display-user.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-user'
ERROR in ./src/app/edit-user/edit-user.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/edit-user'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-pick-datetime' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/app/add-auctionbatch/add-auctionbatch.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-pick-datetime' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/add-auctionbatch'
ERROR in ./src/app/display-invoice/display-invoice.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-pick-datetime' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-invoice'
ERROR in ./src/app/display-user/display-user.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-pick-datetime' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-user'
ERROR in ./src/app/edit-user/edit-user.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-pick-datetime' in '/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/edit-user'
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-invoice/display-invoice.component.ts (8,24): Cannot find module 'date-fns'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/add-auctionbatch/add-auctionbatch.module.ts (7,38): Cannot find module 'ng-pick-datetime'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/add-auctionbatch/add-auctionbatch.component.ts (6,24): Cannot find module 'date-fns'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/edit-user/edit-user.module.ts (9,38): Cannot find module 'ng-pick-datetime'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/app.module.ts (49,38): Cannot find module 'ng-pick-datetime'.
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/ngx-chips/ngx-chips.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:493:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-user/display-user.module.ts (9,38): Cannot find module 'ng-pick-datetime'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/edit-user/edit-user.component.ts (8,24): Cannot find module 'date-fns'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-invoice/display-invoice.module.ts (9,38): Cannot find module 'ng-pick-datetime'.
ERROR in /home/linux/Pjkts/clones/alwataneyaangularwebsite/src/app/display-user/display-user.component.ts (8,24): Cannot find module 'date-fns'.
```

Comment: You could mention exactly what conflicts you have and what packages are missing. The output of `npm install` would also help.

Comment: i updated the question to provide `npm install` running result

Comment: it's possible that packages were added without using --save or --save-dev, in which case you'll need to figure out which ones are missing and add them yourself

Comment: @BlackICE i tried to make like that, but i couldn't get compatible packages

Comment: @MohamedMamdouh will you please reinstall the npm.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `node_modules` directory and  `package-lock.json`.
Then run:

```
npm i
```

It will install all the dependencies.
Make sure you make a backup of package-lock.json file. 
After installing put it back in its place.

Comment: i did, deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` defore running `npm i`.

Comment: Try this then:   npm i -g recursive-install